# right tool to filter the UUID from the output of blkid program (using grep, cut, or awk, e.t.c)

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I want to filter the output of the blkid to get the UUID.

The output of blkid looks like

**CASE 1:-**

```
$ blkid
/dev/sda2: LABEL="A" UUID="4CC9-0015"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="B" UUID="70CF-169F"
/dev/sda1: LABEL=" NTFS_partition" UUID="3830C24D30C21234"
```

In somecases the output of blkid looks like

**CASE 2:-**

```
$ blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="d7ec380e-2521-4fe5-bd8e-b7c02ce41601" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="fc54f19a-8ec7-418b-8eca-fbc1af34e57f" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda3: UUID="6f218da5-3ba3-4647-a44d-a7be19a64e7a" TYPE="swap"
```

I want to filter out the UUID.

Using the combination of **grep** and **cut** it can be done as

```
/sbin/blkid | /bin/grep 'sda1' | /bin/grep -o -E 'UUID="[a-zA-Z|0-9|\-]*' | /bin/cut -c 7-
```

I have tried using **awk** , **grep** and **cut** as below for filtering the UUID

```
$ /sbin/blkid | /bin/grep 'sda1' | /usr/bin/awk '{print $2}' | /bin/sed 's/\"//g' | cut -c 7-
7ec380e-2521-4fe5-bd8e-b7c02ce41601
```

The above command(which uses awk) is not reliable since sometimes an extra field such as LABEL may be present in the output of the **blkid** program as shown in the above output.

What is the best way to create a command using **awk** which works reliably?
Please post if any other elegant method exits for the job using bin and core utils. I dont want to use perl or python since this has to be run on busybox.

NOTE:-I am using **busybox** blkid to which **/dev/sda1** can not be passed as the args(the version i am using does not support it) hence the grep to filter the line.

**UPDATE :-** added  the CASE 2: -output to show that field position can not be relied upon.

Comment: I do simply:
`sudo blkid | cut -d' ' -f2 | cut -d\" -f2`

Comment: field positions can not be relied upon. sample out of the program is $ blkid
/dev/sda2: LABEL="A" UUID="4CC9-0015"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="B" UUID="70CF-169F"
/dev/sda1: LABEL=" NTFS_partition" UUID="3830C24D30C21234"
/usr/etc/udev/rules.d # blkid | cut -d' ' -f2 | cut -d\" -f2 
A
B

Comment: check this: `sudo blkid | grep -oP 'UUID=[0-9a-zA-Z"-]+'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For all the UUID's, you can do :

```
$ blkid | sed -n 's/.*UUID=\"\([^\"]*\)\".*/\1/p' 
d7ec380e-2521-4fe5-bd8e-b7c02ce41601
fc54f19a-8ec7-418b-8eca-fbc1af34e57f
6f218da5-3ba3-4647-a44d-a7be19a64e7a
```

Say, only for a specific sda1:

```
$ blkid | sed -n '/sda1/s/.*UUID=\"\([^\"]*\)\".*/\1/p' 
d7ec380e-2521-4fe5-bd8e-b7c02ce41601
```

The sed command tries to group the contents present within the double quotes after the UUID keyword, and replaces the entire line with the token.

Comment: Warning! This will yield **INCORRECT** UUID on GPT! On GPT, besides UUID there is also PARTUUID, so your regexp will match on that, as it is usually later on in the line. To fix, add a space before the "UUID".

Also, to get an UUID for a specific drive, you don't need to parse it, just use `blkid <device>`

Comment: If you have labels on the devices (you should), you can filter by label, so if your volume is moved or mounted with another device id, you can always find the UUID: `blkid -t LABEL=your-tag -s UUID -o value`

Answer (score 92):

Why are you making it so complex?

Try this:

```
# blkid -s UUID -o value
d7ec380e-2521-4fe5-bd8e-b7c02ce41601
fc54f19a-8ec7-418b-8eca-fbc1af34e57f
6f218da5-3ba3-4647-a44d-a7be19a64e7a
```

Or this:

```
# blkid -s UUID -o value /dev/sda1
d7ec380e-2521-4fe5-bd8e-b7c02ce41601
```

Install proper blkid package if you don't have it:

```
sudo apt-get install util-linux
sudo yum install util-linux
```

Comment: Great! Better than using regex.

Comment: looks great if you have a real blkid, but not on busybox's blkid -- thats why people are looking for parsing solutions

Answer (score 2):

Here's a short `awk` solution:

```
blkid | awk 'BEGIN{FS="[=\"]"} {print $(NF-1)}'
```

**Output:**

```
4CC9-0015
70CF-169F
3830C24D30C21234
```

**Explanation:**

- `BEGIN{FS="[=\"]"}` : Use `=` and `"` as delimiters
- `{print $(NF-1)}`: `NF` stands of Number of Fields; here we print the 2nd to last field
- This is based on the consistent structure of blkid output: `UUID` in quotes is at the end of each line.

**Alternatively:**

```
blkid | awk 'BEGIN{FS="="} {print $NF}' | sed 's/"//g'
```

Comment: Field postion can not be relied on, please look at the CASE 2:-  output for which the solution does not work.

Answer (score 0):

#### data.txt

```
/dev/sda2: LABEL="A" UUID="4CC9-0015"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="B" UUID="70CF-169F"
/dev/sda1: LABEL=" NTFS_partition" UUID="3830C24D30C21234"
```

#### `awk` and `sed` combination

```
cat data.txt | awk 'BEGIN{FS="UUID";RS="\n"} {print $2}' | sed -e 's/=//'  -e 's/"//g'
```

#### Explanation:

1. Set the Field Separator to the string 'UUID', `$2` will give the rest output
2. use sed then to remove the `=` and `"` as shown where `-e` is a switch so that you can give multiple sed commands/expression in one.
3. All occurrences of `"` are removed using the ending `g` option i.e. global.

Comment: Field postion can not be relied on, please look at the CASE 2:-  output for which the solution does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The question has a "e.t.c" so I'm going to assume python is one of the options ;)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess, re, json

# get blkid output
blkid = subprocess.check_output(["blkid"]).decode('utf-8')


devices = []
for line in [x for x in blkid.split('\n') if x]:
        parameters = line.split()
        for idx, parameter in enumerate(parameters):
                if idx is 0:
                        devices.append({"DEVICE": re.sub(r':$','',parameter)})
                        continue

                key_and_value = parameter.split('=')
                devices[-1].update({
                        key_and_value[0]: re.sub(r'"','',key_and_value[1])
                })


uuids = [{dev['DEVICE']: dev['UUID']} for dev in devices if 'UUID' in dev.keys()]
print(json.dumps(uuids, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Although, this is probably overkill and quite a few error handling/optimization is missing from this script XD

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using busybox in an initramfs and you are waiting for your e.g. USB drive with the rootfs on it to become available.

You could use the following awk script (busybox awk compliant).

```
# cat get-ruuid.awk 
BEGIN {
  ruuid=ENVIRON["RUUID"]
}

/^\/dev\/sd[a-z]/ {
  if (index($0, tolower(ruuid)) || index($0, toupper(ruuid))) {
    split($1, parts, ":")
    printf("%s\n", parts[1])
    exit(0) # Return success and stop further scanning.
  }
}

END {
  exit(1) # If we reach the end, it means RUUID was not found.
}
```

Call it as follows from e.g. the init script; this is not the most ideal way.

```
# The UUID of your root partition
export RUUID="<put proper uuid value here>"

for x in 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ; do
  mdev -s
  found=$(blkid | awk -f ./get-ruuid.awk)
  test -z $found || break; # If no longer zero length, break the loop.
  sleep 1
done
```

But if this is the only reason why you would want to have an initramfs, I would use the 'root=PARTUUID=... waitroot' Linux kernel command line option. Check the kernel docs and sources.

Get the proper PARTUUID (NOT UUID) of your root partition with the blkid command.